# How to hide same id rows in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a DataGridView where I get values by id but sometimes id have more than one entries on same date so it shows multiple entries in DataGridView of same id but I want to hide all of them except first one.  I don't want to remove them because I am loading that entries in new form. How can I get this?

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
  If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(0).Value Then
    Dim z = DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1
    z.visible = False
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Are you adding values straight to the `DataGridView` or you have some collection of items or `DataTable` which datagridview displays? It would help to know/see how data added to the `DataGridView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for-loop instead of the for-each loop would make this easier, starting on the second row and always looking back one row:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
  If Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) = 
     Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(0).Value) Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Visible = False
  End If
Next
```

Comment: how to add text criteria with this code suppose if cell(0) has apple and cell(2) has same id hide all duplicate rows of apple or cell(0) has apple, orange,peach and cell(2) has its id  in cell(2) then hide all duplicates.

Comment: @pankajbabbar I would ask a new question on that.  Try showing what the grid would look like because your description is a little confusing.